Blank page when protecting route with react router
I have followed several guides and questions on stack overflow with no luck.
I want to set up protected routes, so going to example /highscores would redirect user to /login if not signed in.
Currently if not signed in and going to /highscores, i just get a blank page, if im signed in and go to highscores i get redirected to login..
The pages and auth token works with value in other parts of the system. But in none of the scenarios does it even print "No AUTHH" or "GOT AUTHHH"
"react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
"react": "^18.2.0"
In my index.jsx
export const AuthContext = createContext("");
 const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState("");
useEffect(() => {
    let token = Cookies.get("authToken")
    setAuthToken(token);

/../
return (
      <TimerProvider>
 <AuthContext.Provider value={{authToken, setAuthToken}}>
<BrowserRouter>
<FixedLayout>
<Routes>
  <Route
  element={<PrivateRoute/>}>
    <Route path="/highscores" element={<HighScoresPage/>}/>
  </Route>
 </Routes>
</FixedLayout>
</BrowserRouter>
</AuthContext.Provider>
</TimerProvider> )

and my PrivateRoute.jsx
import { AuthContext } from "./index";
import React, {useContext} from 'react'
import {Navigate} from "react-router-dom"

const PrivateRoute = ({children}) => {
    const { authToken } = useContext(AuthContext);


    if(!authToken) {
        console.log("No AUTHH")
        return <Navigate to="/login" />
    }

        console.log("GOT AUTHHH")
        return children


};

export default PrivateRoute;


PrivateRoute is a layout route component so it should render an Outlet for the nested routes instead of the children prop as there are no children to render.
